# how to add a second onClick listener without removing the first one? React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The question seems simple, but it doesn't work for me :(
I am adding listeners depending on the conditions.

If the first condition is true, I add a function

```
ref.current.onclick = ()=> {function1()}
```

If the second condition is true, I add the second function

```
ref.current.onclick = ()=> {function2()}
```

This removes the first function. How to add a second function without deleting the first?

I tried:

```
ref.current.onclick = ()=> {ref.current.onclick, function2()}

ref.current.onclick = ()=> {ref.current.onclick(), function2()}

ref.current.onclick = ()=> {()=>ref.current.onclick(), function2()}
```

This does not work

---

**Something in my question confuses readers)
I have no problem with conditions.
I can't add a second function to the onClick event without removing the first one.**

Comment: Could you check the condition inside a higher level function that then calls function1/function2? Sorry if this is not relevant to your situation, just seems like the simplest fix without seeing the big picture.

Comment: @BransonSmith I think I phrased the question wrong. I have no problem with conditions. I can't add event 2 without removing event 1.

Comment: Roman, there's only one `onclick` on an element. If you assign something, anything, to it, it's going to replace whatever was there before. Now, because we're talking about functions, instead of replacing `A()` with `B()`, you replace it with `C()`, which looks like this: `() => {A(); B();}` Which means when the click is triggered, both `A()` and `B()` are run, not only `B()`.

Comment: @Roman Yes, as tao suggested, (and I described in my comment) you can create one function that is responsible for handling the conditions and calling your current functions when appropriate. Function A and B in taos comment are function1 and function2 in your question. Then create function3 which is responsible for either calling function1 or function2 based on the condition. Then set onClick={function3}

Comment: @BransonSmith I cannot do as you suggest.First I add onClick = ()=>{A()} and then I don't need to do something like onClick = ()=> {onClick(); B()}. At the time of adding B(), I don't have access to A(). How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a conditional (ternary) operator like this:

```
{YourCondition ? ref.current.onclick = ()=> {function1()} : ref.current.onclick = ()=> {function2()}}
```

For more informations, click [on this link to see the full documentation about conditional rendering, which will help you.](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/conditional-rendering#conditional-ternary-operator--)

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to communicate this point clearly in the comments, so here is an example. Without more context of your problem (what is your "condition"?) it is hard to know if this solves your problem or not. Hope it helps though.

Below is a react component that has conditional behavior when you click "Process Number".

If the number is odd, function A gets called.
If the number is even, function B gets called.

But, the onClick function is always the same: "processNumber"

The key concept here is the processNumber function that is able to handle the condition and call A or B accordingly. You could add all kinds of logic in here, but the onClick would always point to processNumber, not some other function.

```
//EvenOddComponent.js
import { useState } from 'react';

export default function EvenOddComponent() {

    const [number, setNumber] = useState(1)

    function A() {
        console.log('the number is odd')
    }
    function B() {
        console.log('the number is even')
    }

    function processNumber() {
        if (number % 2 != 0) {
            A()
        } else {
          B()
        }
    }

    return <div>
         <>{number}</>
         <button onClick={() => setNumber(number + 1)}>Increment Number</button>
         <button onClick={processNumber}>Process Number</button> 
    </div>
}
```

An alternative solution could be to pass the onClick function in as a prop like this:

```
export default function funcCaller(props) {
    return <button onClick={props.functionToCall}>Do thing</button>
}
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help! My problem is that I am trying to add B() when A() is already added. to create C() I need to somehow extract A() from onClick and put A()+B() into C(). At the time of adding B() I don't have access to function A(), only access to B() and ref.current.onclick

Comment: Ok, then it sounds like you can just put the function in a variable, and change it when appropriate

Comment: If you are still stumped it may be helpful to post your code and more importantly 
 explain the actual condition that gives access to A/B - good luck either way!

Comment: https://codepen.io/romanusname/pen/gOjVWLX?editors=0010 / I made a very simple example to demonstrate the problem @BransonSmith